# Oracle table is locked for inserts during a procedure execution but allows updates

Tags: indexing, oracle11g, locking, database-partitioning

We have a procedure which does operation on multiple records in multiple tables, in some cases the procedure needs to insert in a table named `TAX`, when this insert happens another table named `PAYMENT` is locked for insertion, but not for update.

So if another transaction tries to insert in `PAYMENT` it waits till completion of the procedure, but transactions which try to update `PAYMENT` don't wait.

The `TAX` table have two foreign keys to `PAYMENT`, one is nullable and the other one is mandatory, and there exist two indexes on `TAX` table, one on `FK_PAY` (the mandatory one) and one on `(FK_PAY_SETTLEMENT, ID)` (the optional one with a mandatory `ID` column).

What can I do to prevent this lock on `PAYMENT` table, because this table is target of high concurrent inserts.

---

I shall mention that `PAYMENT` table is partitioned on hash of `id`, and `TAX` is partitioned by reference on `FK_PAY` (the mandatory reference).

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key reference(in the Tax table) is preventing the Insert operation on the Payment table.

The Update operation(in Payment table) works as it is updating old data in the table(no primary key or any other key conflict).

Comment: I have indexes on both of foreign keys, even the optional foreign key has a multi-column index `(fk_pay, id)` so, it will always exist in the index.

Comment: The FOREIGN KEY constraint prevents invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the table it points to. Since you are trying an insert operation on Payment table, while there is already an insert operation going on in Tax table, foreign key constraint is not allowing it. check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I know what foreign key is. My insert operations don't violate the foreign key constraints. We have too many inserts in two tables in a single transaction, and have not encounter such problem in other cases.

Comment: How are the Insert operations executing? First there is an Insert on TAX table then on PAYMENT table or at the same time?

Comment: The procedure on certain condition inserts in `TAX` table, but just updates `PAYMENT` table (and a few other tables).

Comment: So, when the procedure is running, it won't allow any parallel Insert operation in the PAYMENT table. But update will be allowed.

Comment: This only happens when a record in `TAX` is inserted, but other times when the procedure updates and inserts in other tables no locking happens.